# FInd Java Libraries from Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

So this might be a dumb question but, In Mac Terminal is there a command so that I can just say > find java and it will print the whole path to my java libraries? For greater context I've downloaded JUnit4 and I want to add the jar files to the java library but, well, I'm not sure where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this command :

```
# find / -path '*/bin/java'
```

Comment: That found it, but is there a way so that it only prints the path, cause I got a lot of output saying where it wasn't